JetpackCompose: Spacer with "weight(1f)" does not work in Column
I expect to use compose to implement the following style:
expected
The above screenshot effect is implemented using flex in HTML,and I try to use Jetpack Compose to reproduce this effect,but I got:
compose
BottomText should be at the bottom of the card (as shown in the picture below), but Spacer does not seem to work:
expected
Here is my compose code:
@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun TestPreview() {
    LazyColumn {
        item {
            TestItem("kkk")
        }
        item {
            TestItem("k".repeat(200))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestItem(content: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(80.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Green),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text("123", fontSize = 18.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            Text("Content: $content")

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            Text("Bottom Text", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow))
        }
    }
}

how to fix it?
expected

The issue in your code is that the Column is not being able to fillMaxSize due to less content and hence, weight modifier won't work. You need to provide some minimum height in Column.
So, if your Box height is static(the red one), then you can apply minimum height in Column content and remove Spacer with weight and for fixing width issue in Bottom Text, you can use fillMaxWidth modifier:
@Composable
fun TestItem(content: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(80.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .heightIn(min = 80.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Green),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text("123", fontSize = 18.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            Text("Content: $content")

            Text("Bottom Text", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Yellow))
        }
    }
}


Moreover, if you want to align 123 text and content text then you will have to wrap them in separate Column as parent Column has vertical alignment as SpaceBetween

Thank you for your response. After posting this issue, I suddenly thought of the same approach as you did, and it indeed works. Thank you for explaining the implementation principles of this method.
